# Send custom data as object using WCF

Tags: wcf, object

In my latest project, I wish to send custom data as an object using WCF. Reason for this is that I won't have to update each client when a new data class is introduced.
However, when I try to send this data, it never arrives at the client side.

To give a short example:
A custom class:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyData
     {
     [DataMember]
     public string Name { get ;set; }
     [DataMember]
     public id Value { get; set; }

     public MyData(string name, id value)
     {
     this.Name = name;
     this.Value = value;
     }
}
```

When I want to send this to the client, I use:

```
object obj = new MyData("test",1);
service.SendDataToClient(obj);
```

The client never receives this event from the service when I send it as object. However, when I send it as MyData instead of object, it works as it should. How can I send this as object?

Comment: NOTE: the Value-property has to be an int instead of id

Comment: Won't you have to update the client anyway when a new data class is introduced?  How else will the client create the new object to send?

Comment: The client sends the received data to a UserControl found in a at-compiletime-unknown assembly, so the client doesn't have to know the custom class (since the UserControls expect an array of objects which they then convert to the right type)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send custom data the easy way is using `XElement` instead of object. Another approach is defining all possible transfered types by `ServicKnownTypeAttribute` or creating generic resolver (in such case you must share contract assembly between client and service). Check [this great article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx).

Comment: You can't cast a custom data object to XElement, can you? XElement is used in XML, I don't wish to serialize my data to xml before sending it. It's possible to send for example a bool as an object, so why can't I send my own classes as object?